# Different Values in Memory when using NSData vs NSMutableData

Tags: objective-c, memory

I'm trying to write some code that assembles packets to send over a network; however, I've run into problems with the assembled packets. Here's some code illustrating my situation:

```
NSMutableData *data1 = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:3];
NSData * data2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:(unsigned char[]){0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA} length:3];
[data1 appendBytes:(unsigned char[]){0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA} length: 3];
```

When I set a breakpoint and read the values of memory for `*data1` and `*data2`, `data1` only has garbage values in it, whereas `data2` will have the `0xAA`'s in memory.

I looked at the Apple developer reference, but didn't seem to find anything related. One interesting thing I noted though, was that the initialization of `data1` should have zeroed out the bytes, which I'm also not really seeing.

So I'm wondering if there's some obvious mistake I'm making in my code, or some fundamental misunderstanding of the NSData/MutableData objects, seeing as I'm pretty new to Objective C? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I'm dumb...turns out if I look at memory of `data1`, not `*data1`, I can find the values that I append.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the wrong values, I should have been looking at memory of `data1` instead of `*data1`.